# image size is not adjusting in bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am wanting to use carousel to scroll through different pictures as part of a portfolio site in a "my work" section. I am using the Bootstrap grid system to divide the work into two columns: one for the image and one for the description fo the work. The HTML for this looks like below:

`

```
<div class="container" id="work-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col image-container" id="qc-image">

            <img style="width: 30rem;" src="./assets/img/image.png">

            </div>
            <div class="col">

                <h2 style="color: #000000; text-align: center;">Name Of Project</h2>

            </div>

        </div>


    </div>
```

The images in the first column are screenshots. What I want to do is make a carousel type of effect that lets the user click on the circles at the bottom of the image and scroll through different images of the screenshots as a sort of preview, but sizing bootstrap carousel is proving to be difficult in doing this.

I impose the following code for the carousel slides thinking it would work, but the size of the images is the size you would expect a full sized carousel image to be. I set it to 100%, thinking it would match the width of the col but that didn't work.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New York">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Would anyone be able to shed some light on how to effectively make this? I'm open to the idea that a bootstrap carousel is not the best way to go about what I'm trying to do, but I'm not totally sure where to go from there, perhaps Node.js?

Answer (score 0):

use this for assigning the image and content and adjust the col-md-* value according to your requirement and than assign width 100% to image

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-*">
      <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-*">
      <h2> content </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So how would the carousel itself work in this example? Would you put multiple images  within `<div class="cold-md-*">` ?

Comment: i did not understand what you want to say

Comment: but in this example i show you for one item in carousel and col-md-* refers to the grid you want to use you can take col-md-6 col-md-4 etc of your choice

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your `column <div>s` proper `classes` to tell bootstrap how to size them. In `bootstrap` a `<div>` is divided into `12 imaginary columns`, regardless of the width of the `<div>`.

So by doing this:

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
// width of 6 columns when window resolution is extra small
```

we are telling `bootstrap` to give this `<div>` a width of `50%` of its `parent` width.

You can also do this for example:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
// when at extra small width is 6 columns, when at medium switch to 3 columns
```

After properly sizing the `<div>s`, and including the `jQuery` and `bootstrap` scripts (and `bootstrap CSS`), things should just work.

Also, no need to give the `images` `height` and `width`, they should `automatically` acquire the `maximum width` of their `container` and use `auto height`.

**Here is the code** (run the snippet at the bottom):

```html
<!-- jQuery, Bootstrap scripts and bootstrap CSS -->
<!-- put CSS in the head of the HTML doc, put scripts in head or bottom of the body -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="work-container">
  <div class="row">

      <!-- Carousel -->
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="item active">
               <img src="http://www.quotemaster.org/images/b0/b0de398d580fe0cfc6431ec118c16cee.jpg" alt="Flower" />
              </div>
              <div class="item">
               <img src="http://ibmathsworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/IB-Examples.jpg" alt="Example" />
              </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- End of id myCarousel -->
      </div>
      <!-- End of col-xs-6 -->
    
      <!-- Content -->
      <div class="col-xs-6">
          <h2> content </h2>
          <div>
              <p>yeah, this is some content</p>
          </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End of col-xs-6 -->

  </div>
  <!-- End of row -->
</div>
<!-- End of work-container -->
```

**Note:** I added some example content and some example images of different height and width to demonstrate resizing